# Remapping Columns in ViewModel after changing them in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm hoping someone could help me with this problem.  I created a model in my ASP MVC 4 project, which was fine, all working ok.  But I changed some of the names of the columns in the sql server database due to spaces in some of the column names that was causing me grief, but now when I run the project I get an exception error saying "invalid column names" in the columns that I have renamed, even though I have made sure they match both in my model and on my database?

My question is, do I have to remap the columns in my mvc viewmodel, getting them to recognise that I have changed the column names?

Also, when you create your viewmodel, do you have to list all column names even if you don't require them all?  Say you need column numbers 3, 9, 11 and 18 but, don't require the columns inbetween?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to remap or update the database in Entity Framework Model or whatever ORM you are using. After that you need to use the field name in model just like SQL table.

```
In mvc viewmodel you just have to mention those fields which are required, no 
need to include all fields like model.
```

Comment: Hi Shalin, its entity framework I am using, so I would just remap the model and it will recongise the changes I have made to SQL Server?

Comment: @ullevi83 Yes. When you go in the Model.edmx designer view. You have to delete all the tables that you have modified & then again add them back to the model by clicking on "Update the Model from Database".

Comment: Thanks Shalin for all your help. I found this link also in MSDN if it helps someone http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716705(v=vs.100).aspx